# Consonant vs. Dissonant Major Thirds: Historical Process and Significance of Tuning System

Tags: theory, tuning, history, intervals, just-intonation

In the comments to the question [Why is the fourth against the bass considered a dissonance?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/127367/70803), I wrote

> A 5:4 third was considered dissonant until musical tastes changed and declared it consonant.

To which @phoog replied

> In the days in which major thirds were considered dissonant, Pythagorean tuning prevailed. Those were 81:64 thirds, not 5:4.

**What was the process of (major) thirds shifting from dissonances to consonances, and did the change in tuning play a significant role in that shift?**

Comment: I'm mulling over an answer but I'm not sure when I'm going to have time to sit down and write it out.